# apache HTMLUNIT..... PROBLEM in handling javascript

Tags: java, apache, authentication, webclient, login-script

I want to login to a website (http://www.orkut.com) through

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient
```

But when I click on the "Submit" button, it doesn't take me to the expected page that should come after login. Instead it returns the same login page again. In clear sense, there is some problem in login. When I try the same code with sites that doen't have javascript, it works fine so I think I am not able to handle scripts.

I am trying using the follwoing code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    try {
        HtmlPage loginPage = webClient.getPage(new URL("https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=orkut&hl=en-US&rm=false&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.orkut.com%2FRedirLogin%3Fmsg%3D0%26page%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.orkut.co.in%252FHome.aspx&cd=IN&passive=true&skipvpage=true&sendvemail=false"));
        System.out.println(loginPage.getTextContent());
        List<HtmlForm> forms = loginPage.getForms();
        HtmlForm loginForm = forms.get(0);
        HtmlInput username = loginForm.getInputByName("Email");
        HtmlInput password = loginForm.getInputByName("Passwd");
        HtmlInput submit = loginForm.getInputByName("signIn");
        username.setNodeValue("username");
        password.setNodeValue("password");
        HtmlPage homePage = submit.click();
        Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        System.out.println(homePage.getTextContent());
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When we do click on the "submit" button, in actual it calls first this function

```
onsubmit="return(gaia_onLoginSubmit());"
```

specified as the attribute of the form below

```
<form id="gaia_loginform" action="https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?service=orkut" method="post"
    onsubmit="return(gaia_onLoginSubmit());">
```

Can anyone help me in this.

NOTE: I WILL PAY FOR THE SOLUTION

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to their site](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/javascript.html) the JavaScript support is provided by [Mozilla Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino), so maybe all you need is to add it to your classpath (and perhaps fiddle with some configurations).

Also, HtmlUnit has [professional support](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/professionalSupport.html)

Comment: I have already posted my problem to the HtmlUnit mailing list (htmlunit-user@lists.sourceforge.net) and HtmlUnit professional support (http://www.efficient-webtesting.com)

I have installed the Mozzilla Rhino and have added it to my classpath. Can you please tell me what configuration I need to modify.

Comment: Please set the com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript looger to debug level, so you can see what is being executed.