# HtmlUnit - opening javascript page

Tags: javascript, primefaces, htmlunit

When trying to open my page (.../admin) with HtmlUnit test, I get the following error:

```
JavaScript error loading page http://.../admin/home.jsf: syntax error     (http://.../admin/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces#14)
```

I tried to disable JavaScript with:

```
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false)
```

and page opened successfully. But, with JavaScript disabled, click on my login button is not working, so I wanted to enable JavaScript again before the click. Then the following error occurs:

```
JavaScript error loading page http://.../admin/home.jsf: ReferenceError: "PrimeFaces" is not defined.
```

My questions are:

1. is there a different way to override the syntax error when opening JavaScript page, except disabling JavaScript?
2. how to fix '"PrimeFaces" is not defined' error?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: it appears that your syntax error is happening while defining PrimeFaces, I suggest you deal with that error, rather than trying to silence it. I would take a look in a javascript debugger (firebug, chrome developer tools, whatever tool you like best).

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536896/apache-htmlunit-problem-in-handling-javascript?rq=1
as general, the library was written with simple javascript in mind and at least 2 years ago I've failed to work with any more complex AJAX site, jQuery being one of the most complex javascript tools nowadays